# No opposition filed within time limit

Tags: expired-patent

what do think about patents no. EP0529765A1 and no. EP0529766A1 ? The status both is: "No opposition filed within time limit" (Status updated on 18.07.1997). Does it means the patents expired ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

When a European patent application is in order for grant, it may be opposed within 9 months by any person ([EPC art 99](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/epc/2016/e/ar99.html)). This is initiated by another person filing a notice of opposition.

Consequently, if no notice of opposition is filed within the 9 months, the event "no opposition filed within time limit" occurs.

It does not mean that the patents have expired. They may or may not have expired, but that's separate from whether an opposition is filed.